# Adam Optimizer Not Working on cost function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I wanted to make own neural network for MNIST data set and for that using tensorflow i am writing the code
imported library  and dataset
then done one hot encoding
and after all done the weights and baises assignment and then done the forward propagation with the random values and for back propagation and cost minimization used a loss function to do so
but unable to use the optimizer dont know why

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist import load_data

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_data()

y_train_onehot = tf.one_hot(y_train,10)
y_test_onehot = tf.one_hot(y_test,10)


n_input = 784
n_hidden_1 = 256
n_hidden_2 = 256
n_classes = 10

weights = {
    "h1" : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_input,n_hidden_1]),trainable=True),
            #here we require 784x256 random values
    "h2" : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1,n_hidden_2]),trainable = True),
            #here we require 256x256 random values
    
    'out' : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2,n_classes]),trainable = True)
            #here we require 256x10 random values
}

#similarly for biases

biases = {
    "h1" : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1]),trainable = True),
    "h2" : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2]),trainable = True),
    'out' : tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_classes]),trainable = True)
}

def ForwardPropagation(x, weights, biases):
    
    #giving net input to hidden layer1
    in_layer1 = tf.add( tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['h1'])
    #giving net output of hidden layer1
    out_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(in_layer1)
    
    in_layer2 = tf.add( tf.matmul(out_layer1, weights['h2']), biases['h2'])
    out_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(in_layer2)
    
    output = tf.add( tf.matmul(out_layer2, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return output

x_train_modified = tf.reshape(x_train , shape=[60000,784])
x_train_modified = tf.cast(x_train_modified, dtype=tf.float32)
x_train_modified

pred = ForwardPropagation(x_train_modified,weights,biases)
predictions = tf.argmax(pred,1)

y = y_train_onehot
actualvalues = tf.argmax(y,1)
actualvalues

loss = lambda : tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= pred , labels = y))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
optimize = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list=[weights['h1'],weights['h2'],weights['out'],biases['h1'],biases['h2'],biases['out']])
```

after running this giives a error like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [30], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
----> 2 optimize = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list=[weights['h1'],weights['h2'],weights['out'],biases['h1'],biases['h2'],biases['out']])

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:539, in OptimizerV2.minimize(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss, name, tape)
    507 """Minimize `loss` by updating `var_list`.
    508 
    509 This method simply computes gradient using `tf.GradientTape` and calls
   (...)
    535 
    536 """
    537 grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
    538     loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape)
--> 539 return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:640, in OptimizerV2.apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, name, experimental_aggregate_gradients)
    599 def apply_gradients(self,
    600                     grads_and_vars,
    601                     name=None,
    602                     experimental_aggregate_gradients=True):
    603   """Apply gradients to variables.
    604 
    605   This is the second part of `minimize()`. It returns an `Operation` that
   (...)
    638     RuntimeError: If called in a cross-replica context.
    639   """
--> 640   grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    641   var_list = [v for (_, v) in grads_and_vars]
    643   with tf.name_scope(self._name):
    644     # Create iteration if necessary.

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\utils.py:73, in filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     71 if not filtered:
     72   variable = ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],)
---> 73   raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
     74                    f"Provided `grads_and_vars` is {grads_and_vars}.")
     75 if vars_with_empty_grads:
     76   logging.warning(
     77       ("Gradients do not exist for variables %s when minimizing the loss. "
     78        "If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss`"
     79        "argument?"),
     80       ([v.name for v in vars_with_empty_grads]))

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(784, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.2042245 ,  1.0065362 ,  0.79206324, ..., -0.889144  ,
        -0.6301114 , -0.9690762 ],
       [ 0.19671327,  0.89678144, -0.0324002 , ...,  2.0764246 ,
        -0.02647609, -0.8672084 ],
       [ 0.07031541,  0.4843207 ,  0.08144156, ..., -0.3354637 ,
         1.2510766 , -0.6774577 ],
       ...,
       [-0.63975966,  0.19986708, -0.9221592 , ...,  1.3540815 ,
        -0.9916273 ,  0.7312357 ],
       [ 0.41351947,  0.43665868,  0.1957417 , ..., -1.7249284 ,
         0.14709948,  1.1250186 ],
       [ 0.48159713,  0.04631708, -0.1402344 , ..., -0.370907  ,
         0.19523837,  0.8853921 ]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(256, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.32486504,  0.8220085 , -0.23714782, ..., -0.62537277,
         1.0147599 ,  0.5973364 ],
       [ 1.308589  , -0.27249494,  0.65963596, ..., -0.4579711 ,
        ...............................
```

after running this just simply provide variable 0 for all and not minimizes the cost and returns the randomly assigned values to the weights and variables

How to fix it?

Comment: _tf.matmul(x, weights['h1'])_? you are multiplying vector with vector, are you sure about that (this is not the cause of your error)

Comment: yes sit that is not something that is causing error actually it is somewhere related with the loss function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not recording gradient, since you are calculating the prediction "before hand", instead you want to allow the optimizer to "record" the operations, in other words, you want to compute the prediction inside the "loss" lambda that you are passing to the optimizer:

```py
loss = lambda : tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits= ForwardPropagation(x_train_modified,weights,biases) , 
        labels = y_train_onehot))
```

also, consider that in your code you are referring to a `y` variable that you have never defined, you probably meant `y_train_onehot` (which I've used in the above snipped)

the reason why this happens, is clearly explained in the `minimize` doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize

Comment: ooh my mistake i mistakenly forget to copy a small section of code from my notebook as i was copying it manualy so i missed

actually i have made the y variable 

```y = y_train_onehot
actualvalues = tf.argmax(y,1)
```
it is like this

Comment: @HarshSingh i'm sorry, what you mean? optimizer will change the value of the variable, try adding a `print(biases["h1"])` before and after the `optimizer.minimize(...)` call, and you will see that the 2 prints have different values

Comment: yes sir i got the values changed very little bit although the acuracy is decreased but it worked but i guess that the accuracy should imporve instead of decreasing but then also few more points to share 
i.e.

(1/2)

Comment: sir after trying your method i was able to over come the error but the ```optimize``` variable is not returning any thing like it gives me something - ```<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=int64, numpy=1>```  and the doc refrence you provided feels like it will solve my issue as i need to record the gradient but i am very beginner to this so i am not able to apply that ```tf.GradientTape``` on my code please kindly help me out sir regarding this

Adding Colab Link For Notebook for your ease : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MrM-M9zNeLkat5vNlTMwR6z5BYFfEjCH?usp=sharing

2

Comment: @HarshSingh you don't need that return value, you just need to call `optimize.minimize` several times, and each time it will update your variables values, ignore the optimizer.minimize return value (it's just how many times you have called minimize, just ignore it)

Comment: ooh yes sir i was missing the iteration part and now you helped me in this i was able to correctly run the code and also got the desired result sir , i was trying hard since 15 days trying figuring out things by own but at last i just created the account here and posted this question and finally it is solved thank you sir for helping me this much with your valuable time, thanks a lot now i can move forward to complete my rest of the codes thank you very much sir.

Comment: @HarshSingh don't worry, if you have more questions, publish them here on stack overflow, and If nobody helps, come back to this comment section, and post a comment, and I'll check your question ASAP, good luck with your project in the meantime

Comment: yes sir definitely , good luck and have a wonderful day sir , i am very thankful for your help. thanks for your wishes sir.